# How to clear an input field in Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I am using [Typeahead](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/) Jquery plugin. Each time I click on the button a Bootstrap modal will be shown and I can select multiple options inside my input.

my problem is :

When I close the modal and reopen it the previous selected values are still shown inside the input. I need to empty cache each time and reload my page so that next time the input will be empty.

I used different ideas when the modal is closed it will reset the input to empty but still not working.

here my ideas :

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead().bind('typeahead:closed', function () {
    $(this).val("");
});
```

or

```
$("#myinput").val('');
```

Any suggestions please ? Here is my code. Thank you for your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

var dataDefaultColumns = [{
            "name": "country",
            "id": "country",
            "type": "Shipment"
        }, {
            "name": "customer name",
            "id": "customer name",
            "type": "Shipment"
        }, {
            "name": "order number",
            "id": "order number",
            "type": "Serial"
        }, {
            "name": "line number",
            "id": "line number",
            "type": "Serial"
        }];


typeof $.typeahead === 'function' && $.typeahead({
  input: ".js-typeahead-input",
  minLength: 0,
  maxItem: false,
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  searchOnFocus: true,
  cancelButton: true, 
  mustSelectItem: true,
  backdropOnFocus: true,
  group: {
    key: "type",
    template: function(item) {
      var type = item.type;
      return type;
    }
  },
  emptyTemplate: 'no result for {{query}}',
  groupOrder: ["Shipment", "Serial"],
  display: ["name"],
  correlativeTemplate: true,
  dropdownFilter: [{
    key: 'type',
    template: '<strong>{{type}}</strong> Report',
    all: 'All Reports'
  }],
  multiselect: {
    matchOn: ["id"],
    data: function() {
      var deferred = $.Deferred();
      return deferred;
    }  
  },

  template: '<span>' +
    '<span class="name">{{name}}</span>' +
    '</span>',
  source: {
    groupName: {
      data: dataDefaultColumns
    }
  } 
});

   $("#mybutton").click(function(){
      $("#myModal").modal('show');  });

  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.2/jquery.typeahead.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="mybutton" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#myModal">Click Me
</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times                   </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Default</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="typeahead__container">
            <div class="typeahead__field">
              <div class="typeahead__query">
                <input id="myinput"
                       class="js-typeahead-input" 
                       name="input[query]"
                       type="search"
                       placeholder="Search"
                       autofocus
                       autocomplete="on">
              </div>          
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Nothing here? https://www.google.nl/search?q=RESET+"jquery-typeahead"

Comment: Like `$('.typeahead').typeahead().on('typeahead:closed', function () {
    $(this).val("");
});`

Comment: @mplungjan  I have already tried it before but it didn't clear my input

Comment: Bind is deprecated. What does a console.logsay in there

Comment: @mplungjan  console.log shows me the input values, it doesn't clear the previous values

Comment: You mean this does not show anything? `$('.typeahead').typeahead().on'typeahead:closed', function () {
console.log("val",this.value);
    $(this).val("");
});`

Comment: @mplungjan yes when i add this part of code it shows me error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string